# Unable to get the text inside the ACE editor from UI using protractor or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor, ace-editor

I am doing BDD Testing for ACE Editor.

Text inside the ace editor is

```
{
"Conditions": {
    "AccountExist": {
        "Fn::Equals": [
            {
                "Ref": "Account"
            },
            ""
        ]
    }.....etc more than 300 lines of JSON cannot paste here
```

The Xpath is used just getting 20 lines!! or is there any way I can initiate ACE Editor in my typescript or javascript or protractor code?

I have elements as below screen shot

I am trying to read the text JSON inside the ACE Editor using Xpath with the help of a protractor I am using the xpath as below

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with protractor but try changing your xpath expression in `return by.xpath` to

```
//div[contains(@class,'ace_content')]//*
```

and see if it works.

Also, it's not clear from your screenshot if that `div` actually has text; so that may be another problem.

Comment: No!, this also getting only first 20 lines from 300 lines of json text inside the ace editor text box

Comment: @Mia In that case, you'll have to find a way to post a more representative sample of the html you're working with.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I get the HTML?

Comment: @Mia It's in whatever the screenshot came from; looks like a browser page - you may need to save the page in the browser. Another option - paste the code before `return by.xpath("....`; this should also show where the html came from.